# Hiding my request from FireBug

Tags: firefox, firebug

I am developing an asp.net web application and I am using a lot of ajax requests. So I need to know how I can hide these requests from firebug. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use AJAX requests; pretty much no. You can check to see if Firebug is running by using:

```
if (window.console && window.console.firebug) {
  //Something - Firebug is active
}
```

However your options in terms of disabling or reducing what people can see are extremely limited and I doubt worth the effort. If you're worried about Firefox crashing you can always recommend that people disable it for your website. (Like what Gmail did).

Even if you succeed blocking Firebug, what's to stop someone to use the WebKit Inspector or IE's Developer Tools to not get the same information? Security through obscurity isn't all that effective.

Comment: Or, say, throwing a packet sniffer across the connection and reading everything from there..